# Is there sorted array with identical and different values in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

List is not sorted but allow you to store identical values. Set is sorted but do not allow to put the same vlue. What array provide both properties: sort and store identical value?

For example

input:
 `32, 3, 8, 1, 22, 4, 8, 22`

Where I can store input data like:

```
1, 3, 4, 8, 8, 22, 22, 32
```

?

Comment: Set is not generally sorted. Set is a interface. SortedSet is a sorted set implementation.

Comment: do you mean a sorted list?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done quite easily: You can sort a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instance with [`Collections.sort(yourList)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) - you now have a sorted collection that can also contain duplicate values.

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(32);
myList.add(3);
myList.add(8);
myList.add(1);
myList.add(22);
myList.add(4);
myList.add(8);
myList.add(22);

System.out.println("Unsorted: " + myList);

Collections.sort(myList);

System.out.println("Sorted: " + myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a normal `ArrayList<E>` implementation and using following command to sort:
`Collections.sort(yourList);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a sorted multiset.  The Java SE libraries don't provide such a class, but the Guava library does:

- The interface [`SortedMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SortedMultiset.html)
- A tree-based implementation [`TreeMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html)

Note that a tree-based multiset has `O(logN)` operations, compared with `O(N)` or worse for insertion or deletion if you try to keep a conventional list or array ordered.